# Get Username for email id in windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

As we can use email id to login to the computer in windows 8 or later, is there any windows API which can return the username from email id?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that. That only answers username part but not email. I'm looking for email

Comment: You did not ask for the email. You asked for the username. Please rephrase your question to make it clearer what you actually want.